# Is it possible to publish app in google play which app used alpha release component of Android? Like WorkManager

Tags: android, google-play, release, android-workmanager

I have used workmanager in my android project.

Here is the version of `WorkManager`.

`def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha11"`

```
`implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"`
```

Now I want to publish my app on google play.

Is there any problem with using alpha release components?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can, but this components can be unstable and lead to crashes

Comment: @pskink i don't think he mean alpha channel on Google console, but components in alpha stage.

Comment: you can release it just fine for sure, but nobody can guarantee that it is stable and bug-free.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can publish, but batter way is use stable version, for make app all device supportive.